# Referencing static field from class in Android's xml layouts

Tags: android

Say I have following `TextView` in layout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtLoginError"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/sz_12dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/foo" />
```

Is it possible that I change `@dimen/sz_12dp` to point to static field in my custom class, for example:

```
public static class MyDimensions {
    public static int topMarginInPixels = 99; // which would be referenced in some fashion like android:layout_marginTop="@class/MyDimensions.topMarginInPixels"
}
```

I am basically looking for a way to "databind" layout element for some experimentation; instead of loading view and then modifying it in code (`findview`, `setWeight`, etc) I would like for view during creation to fetch sizes from my custom class like it fetches it from `R.java`.

NOTE: I know best practices for supporting multiple screens, differences between px & dp, how to provide different res/values directories for different screen sizes, so please response only if you know answer to this questions rather than repeat what [can be read on this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: Assuming the dimension's file have similar behavior to the string's file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643949/can-i-use-a-static-variable-from-a-java-class-in-res-values-styles-xml

Comment: I don't really understand what are you trying to do ... What's wrong in getting the sizes from `dimens` files?

Comment: @gunar sizes from dimens are not editable at runtime

Comment: Indeed, but a `LayoutParam` can change its dimensions at runtime

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to achieve what you described, but if you really want to have pixels and only pixels you can very well put `px` size instead of `dp`, both in XML or in dimens file - but I guess you knew that already.

**EDIT** a dimension cannot be changed indeed at runtime, but it is not even supposed to; if you want to change a dimension at runtime for a view, get its `LayoutParams` object and set its width, height, margin, padding or whatever you want to change.

Comment: Yeah, know that... I've edited question so that I better explain that I'm basically looking for "databinding". Thanks.

Comment: I know I can change LayoutParam, but as you can see in my question "instead of loading view and then modifying it in code (findview, setWeight, etc) I would like for view during creation to fetch sizes from my custom class like it fetches it from R.java". Anyway forget it... I'll wait to see if somebody has some crazy solution, if not, I'll just delete the question since we are just restating things everybody know about already.

Comment: Leave it please ... marked it as a fav; I am curious also, even though I don't really see its practical nature